# Regexp to match anything (including empty string) except character

Tags: regex, grep

I have key.txt

```
key[]
_key_
_key[]
[]key
[]key_
(key,
key
```

and I want to match occurences with anything before `key` except `_`.

`grep [^_]*key key.txt` gives me everything, `grep [^_]?key key.txt` gives me nothing.

I expect

```
key[]
[]key
[]key_
(key,
key
```

Comment: Linked question is not dupe as it pertains to `bash` and answer just mentions 
 `gnu grep` as addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
grep -E '(^|[^_])key' file

key[]
[]key
[]key_
(key,
key
```

Here:

- `-E`: Enabled extended regex (ERE)
- `(^|[^_])`: This part matches start of line of any character that is not `_`
- `key`: match text `key`

---

If you have `gnu-grep` then you can use negative lookbehind with option `-P` (perl regex mode):

```sh
grep -P '(?<!_)key' file
```

Answer (score 2):

A (lengthier) alternative to the solution by `anubhava`:

```
grep 'key' key.txt | grep -v '_key'
```